# jQuery replace the css style with specified class name

Tags: jquery, string, replacewith

i have a string var with html content,check the following

`var dc = "<html><head><style type='text/css' >.round {border:2px solid grey;width:auto;}</style></head> <body></body>";`

Now how can i change the content inside the `.round` scopes.I mean `border:2px solid grey;width:auto;` ??

can i use `replaceWith` or any other techniques ??

Please reply ,Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

a replaceWith will be your best bet, and/or using regular expressions to help grab that bit between "{" and "}".

At the end of the day, all you have is a string so it will just require string manipulation.

Comment: Could you please help me to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed, to replace string inside curly brackets you can use something like this:

```
dc=dc.replace(/\{([^}]+)\}/, "your new string");
```